# Web app to keep another person up-to-date with work I do

Tags: time-management, productivity, sharing

My research advisor has asked me (and I think it'll help me focus too) to write down what exactly I did and how many hours I've worked on my thesis every day.

I was looking for some kind of online-based website or app that allows me to do that, for instance:

- **March 2016**

  - **Day 1**: Worked 4 hours on research; updated code at [GitHub link](https://github.com)
  - **Day 2**: Worked 2 hours on Research; found these [two new articles](http://theonion.com) to read
  - **Day 3**: Worked 6 hours on Research; wrote 2 new sections for [new article](https://docs.google.com)
  - **Day N**: ...
- **April 2016**

  - **Day 1**: ...

Or something like this. Does anybody know anything like that I could use for this purpose?

I've looked at **Trello**, **UpTo** and some other project management software and calendars but none quite suit me.

Comment: Ok. Not sure whether I need more reputation to do that. I'll flag it and say I'd like it to be migrated to the other forum you've mentioned; is that how it works?

Comment: I'll migrate it for you. (P.S. personally I'd suggest a shared Google calendar, add any notes you want in the description field of events)

Comment: Why specifically did Trello and UpTo fail you? From what you describe, it seems even a simple shared text file or spreadsheet might work. What are the exact features you're looking out for that are missing from the solutions you listed?

Comment: You should give Brightpod a shot. A simple yet effective project management tool that should cater to your need. Let me know what you think, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I'd recommend is a combination of a blog and a wiki. You can use the blog as a journal where you write down what you are currently working on, and dump some ideas; and you can use the wiki to store more long term information. For example, if your research requires you to learn about a new mathematical technique, you can put everything you have learned there, so you don't have to come back and read it all again when it is time to write a paper.

For specific sites, there are tons. I have personally used a private repo in Bitbuket for the wiki, and Wordpress for the blog part. They both allow you to keep the content private.

Answer (score 1):

We used a wiki here to keep everybody in a research group up to date with what was going on. Everybody filled in worklogs with what they were doing, adding more or less regular summaries. Smaller groups met weekly, and the leaders (and students working on theses) gathered also weekly to discuss progress.

Answer (score 0):

## [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/)

It has **browser addons** for Chrome and Firefox, so you can track what websites you visit, and how long you spend on each. It even has a separate software to track the time you spend on a specific software that I use.

Below is what I visit today. There will also have a statistic for week, month, year, etc.

[image: image description]